# JavaScript setInterval Function: bug or not?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Here is my current code:

```
var intervalStreet = 1000;
var richPersonOnStreet = false;
var poorPersonOnStreet = false;

function streetIntervalEvent() {
    var peopleRandomChance = Math.random();
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = peopleRandomChance;
    if (peopleRandomChance <= 0.1) {
        richPersonOnStreet = true;
        document.getElementById("streetText").innerHTML = "A rich man is on the street!";
        intervalStreet = 5000;
        setInterval(function(){var richPersonOnStreet = false; document.getElementById("streetText").innerHTML = "Nothing is happening on the street...";}, 5000);
        intervalStreet = 1000;
    }
}
setInterval(streetIntervalEvent, intervalStreet);
```

All of the code looks fine and dandy, but after I leave this program on for a while, the interval becomes completely messed up. Try leaving this address http://jsfiddle.net/w0gerao3/ on for 10 minutes... You will see what I mean.

Is this a fixable bug within the setInterval function?

Comment: Nope, this is a fixable bug with your own code. Calling `setInterval()` from a function that is itself triggered by `setInterval()` is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your code? You set an initial interval after the function declaration, but inside of it you do it again; could this be the reason for the messed up interval?

Comment: Aren't you confused with `setTimeout` and `setInterval`?

Answer (score 0):

You call `streetIntervalEvent` every second.

Every time you call `streetIntervalEvent` you have a 10% chance of calling `function(){var richPersonOnStree...` every 5 seconds.

After 10 minutes you will have ~60 intervals calling that inner function every 5 seconds.

Eventually you would have an infinite number (except the browser would crash first).

---

This is probably fixable, but I have no idea what you are *trying* to achieve in the first place.